# error is :" Incorrect syntax near 'No'". in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

string insert = "insert into ebook(Name,Email,Passeword,Mobile No.)values (@name,@email,@password,@dob,@mobile no.))";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile no.", TextBox5.Text);

int rd = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Response.Redirect("manger.aspx");

con.Close();
```

Comment: You shouldn't have periods in your column names. Spaces (as marc says below) are allowed, but require you to escape the column name.

Comment: I sure hope those aren't the real textbox names but I have a bad feeling they are. Ugh!!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have parameter names like "mobile no." - no spaces, no special characters like dots etc - use `@MobileNo` instead.

If you have SQL Server columns with special chars and spaces - you **must** enclose them in square brackets `[Mobile No.]`

So use this:

```
string insert = "insert into ebook(Name, Email, Passeword, [Mobile No.]) " +
                "values (@name, @email, @password, @dob, @mobileno)";
.....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileno", TextBox5.Text);
```

Furthermore, check this out and avoid using `.AddWithValue()` :

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not relevant according to your question and @"marc_s" has already explained that parameter names shouldn't have intermediate spaces - it's correct and I vote for that but I'd like to highlight some other required modification in your code. Close `SqlConnection` and only after that redirect your page, otherwise `con.Close();` will never be executed.

```
con.Close();
Response.Redirect("manger.aspx");
```